# Eloquent with diferent relationships for same table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i need some hints and what is the best way and pratice with laravel to solve this problem!

I have a main table called colors with the fields category_id and type and i have in my models 2 relationships for the category_id, the bluecategory and redcategory.

In some cases i use the id from bluecategory and in other exemples i use the redcategory id.

Now in one page i want to shows all the results from colors, but i can't do this $data->bluecategory or $data->redcategory because i dont'no what record is using what relationship.

My ideia was using a function to send parameters  category_id and type and inside the function discover what is the correspondente relashion and return the correct result.

But how i can handle this?
Sorry its a bit confuse!

Comment: it's better using Polymorphic Relationships https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships

Comment: @MuhammadDyasYaskur yes and thanks i am not asking for code just some hint for what should i look for, thanks for your time and atencion

Comment: Polymorphic Relationships don't do the job, thanks

Comment: the problem is your database design

Comment: Hello! Can you post a photo of the boards for reference?

Comment: I have solved creating an helper function

Answer (score 0):

You could add a **scope** to your modal and than chain it to your existing query.

Example

```
public function scopeName($query, $catID, $type)
{
        return $query->where('category_id, $catID)
                ->where('type', $type);
}
```